# Cannot access an object's field if it's a type that inherits from another class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am trying to make a c# mod for a game. In order to do so, first I wanted to recreate some classes, methods, etc. in a simpler way. So far I have this code (everything is in the same namespace):

```cs
class MyWeapons
{

    public class SL_Item
    {
        public SL_ItemStats StatsHolder;
        public int New_ItemID;
        public int Target_ItemID;
    }

    public class SL_Weapon : SL_Item
    {
        public bool? Unblockable;
        public float? HealthLeechRatio;
    }

    public class SL_Damage
    {
        public float Damage;
        public string Type;
    }

    public class SL_ItemStats
    {
        public int BaseValue;
    }

    public class SL_WeaponStats : SL_ItemStats
    {
        public List<SL_Damage> BaseDamage;
        public float AttackSpeed;
    }
}
        
        
    public static void Init()
    {

        var myItem = new SL_Weapon()
        {
            StatsHolder = new SL_WeaponStats()
            {
                //adding new SL_Damage to the BaseDamage list when initializing it
                BaseDamage = new List<SL_Damage>() { new SL_Damage { Damage = 25f, Type = "Something" } },
            }
        };
        myItem.StatsHolder.AttackSpeed = 5f;
    }
```

Now, the problem is, that in the last line the program 'thinks' that `AttackSpeed` is a property of `SL_ItemStats` (because `StatsHolder` is of that type; the error says: SL_ItemStats does not contain a definition for `AttackSpeed`...). But the class `SL_WeaponStats` inherits from `SL_ItemStats` and I made `StatsHolder` a new object of the type `SL_WeaponStats`. Now, the thing I absolutely don't understand is that I can access `StatsHolder` properties of the `SL_WeaponStats` class in the object initializer (`BaseDamage` in my code; but I also tried with `AttackSpeed` and it works fine). However I cannot access the same properties after the object (`myItem`) already exists (the last line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works by design.

```cs
public class SL_Item
{
    // you declared StatsHolder as  SL_ItemStats 
    public SL_ItemStats StatsHolder;
 .....
// you derived to its superclass
StatsHolder = new SL_WeaponStats()
```

your expectations are false because `StatsHolder` does not have `AttackSpeed`. The base `SL_WeaponStats` has it.

This works

`((SL_WeaponStats)myItem.StatsHolder).AttackSpeed = 5f;`

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting upon the distinction between an object's *static* type and its *dynamic* type.

The dynamic type of a variable is the type of the object it holds while running.
The static type of a variable is the type it's defined as in the code.

The compiler can only know a variable's static type. `StatsHolder` is defined as a `SL_ItemStats`, so as far as the compiler is concerned, that's all it can be.  T.S.'s answer shows how to enlighten the compiler as to the wider uses of `StatsHolder`.